# Varnish 3.0.3 req.hash_always_miss vs Vary

Tags: hash, varnish, purge

I'm trying to build a system that can purge and regenerate URLs as required for a particular system. I previously was having issues with purging when the system located the object by hash but missed the variant as I didn't have a "purge;" in my vcl_miss (only in my vcl_hit, some guides/example vcl files do not mention this need but the main documentation does [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/purging.html)).

What I'm trying to figure-out is if I need to do something similar for a REGEN call. From my understanding, "set req.hash_always_miss = true;" will mean that the old hash is missed and a new hash object is generated. Subsequent calls will find the new hash, but may still miss that object if there is not an appropriate variant in the cache.

Could someone confirm for me whether a subsequent request missing the variant in the new object will lead directly to a cache miss and fetch, rather than finding any of the variants from the previous object?

Answer (score 1):

hash_always_miss will only influence the current/ongoing request and the cache contents that it replaces. A fetch will always happen, and the object will be put into the cache using the same rules as any other miss/fetch sequence.

The "old" other variants of the same hash are still valid objects and will be served to a client indicating request headers matching the varied headers.

hash_always_miss will replace the current variant, and nothing else.

To answer your question, the second part of your sentence is most correct.